# Accepting User Input in Java

Tags: java, input, libraries

Is it possible to add C++ like input (i.e. without using Scanners or anything; just plain single statement input like "cin>>") in Java using some library or anything?

Comment: Briefly... No. Use the scanner.

Comment: Java can't overload operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not that easy because Java does not support operator overload

you can create a Scanner object

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and read the user input with

```
String s = scan.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Briefly... No. Use the scanner:

Answer (score 0):

You can't have operator overloading and Scanner is in the standard library.

Comment: (Another question which popped in my mind)
If we cant overload operators in JAVA, won't it be difficult to create some kinds of Programs...
Are there any alternative methods for Overloading operators?

Comment: @iluvthee07 Operator overloading is just syntactic sugar. It was left out of Java, because the advantages were considered to be less than the possibilities of confusion.